# How long does it take "Accept (minor edit)" to final decision?

Tags: ieee

I received a decision letter from IEEE ACCESS from two reviewers, stating "Accept (minor edits)", but the editor's decision is "reject and resubmit".
So, I have revised the manuscirpt and submitted it.
My question is, how long does it normally take from the time I submit the revised manuscript (with minor edits to only 2-3 paragraphs) until the final decision is made?

Comment: I don't know about IEEE Access, but I know journals in which this *is* the final decision, i.e., they are just asking you for a potentially edited final version in this way.